# How to scroll the page in Appium + Python

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I create tests using Appium+Python to test IOs app. 
I want to scroll the page. 
Here is the code

```
    def scroll_page(self):
       action = TouchAction(self)
       action.press(BrowsePageElements.firs_element_to_scroll(self)).
              move_to(BrowsePageElements.second_element_to_scroll(self)).perform()
```

When I'm trying to run this function, I get an error

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnitd.jpg)

Could you help me to find out, how to fix this error?

Comment: What is your 'scroll_browser_page' object? Are you sure you are locating your element correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Appium Python has a native `scroll` function. It works for both Android and iOS.

`driver.scroll(origin_el, destination_el, duration=None)`, where duration is an optional argument. This function scrolls `origin_el` to the location of `destination_el`.

[Link to scroll source code](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/261ff54e21980ed1ce6b9268257bbaee669bf78b/appium/webdriver/extensions/action_helpers.py)

The Appium documentation is rather spotty and needs updating. However, the source code is documented well enough to understand and learn the program.

Answer (score 1):

This currently works for me:

```
    ...
    SCROLL_DUR_MS = 3000
    ...
    window_size = self.driver.get_window_size()
    self.scroll_y_top = window_size['height'] * 0.2
    self.scroll_y_bottom = window_size['height'] * 0.8
    self.scroll_x = window_size['width'] * 0.5
    ...

def scroll_up(self):
    self._y_scroll(self.scroll_y_top, self.scroll_y_bottom)

def scroll_down(self):
    self._y_scroll(self.scroll_y_bottom, self.scroll_y_top)

def _y_scroll(self, y_start, y_end):
    actions = TouchAction(self.driver)
    actions.long_press(None, self.scroll_x, y_start, SCROLL_DUR_MS)
    actions.move_to(None, self.scroll_x, y_end)
    actions.perform()
```

It scrolls slowly over 3s because I want it to be controlled, but you could shorten `SCROLL_DUR_MS` (the duration of the scroll action in milliseconds) if you want something more zoomy. I also went away from using elements as the start and/or end points because I wanted something general that would work with any screen content.

For `scroll_y_top` and `scroll_y_bottom` I picked 20% in from the top and bottom of the screen just to make sure I wasn't hitting anything at the borders (like the navigation bar at the top of iOS Preferences or an info bar at the bottom of the app I was working in). I also ran into a "bug" where it wasn't scrolling when I left `scroll_x` as 0, but it turns out that it wasn't registering the left edge as inside the scrolling area for the app I was working in.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the past when i've run into issues scrolling for one reason or another, I've simply swiped using coordinates to scroll down the page.

```
self.driver.swipe(100, 700, 100, 150)
```

Comment: This is method deprecated